How to get token in Blazor WASM (.NET 8)
I use Blazor WASM application (.NET 8) with Keycloak OpenId. The problem is I have no idea how to access the token from code (I want to store it to use later for logout as token_id_hint).
There are no handlers I can add my method to AddOidcAuthentication configuration:
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.MetadataUrl = "https://my-domain.com/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://my-domain.com/realms/my-realm";
    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "website-auth";
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "id_token token";
    options.UserOptions.NameClaim = "preferred_username";
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = ClaimTypes.Role;
    options.UserOptions.ScopeClaim = "scope";
}).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

Also I can't intercept it using IAccessTokenProviderAccessor, it always returns empty token:
var tokenResult = await AccessTokenProvier.RequestAccessToken();

How do I get my token in .NET 8 + OIDC?
